# how can i select multiple rows with string

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

i tried to select the following rows, but it is giving me a debug error. i think  because the actual string is over 256 char. the string without the last 127:127, works. how can i get around this?

'does not work

```
Range("488:488,456:456,455:455,454:454,453:453,448:448,441:441,440:440,439:439,438:438,437:437,436:436,435:435,421:421,414:414,395:395,392:392,391:391,390:390,389:389,388:388,387:387,386:386,385:385,384:384,383:383,382:382,381:381,380:380,379:379,378:378,369:369,127:127").Select
```

'WORKING

```
Range("488:488,456:456,455:455,454:454,453:453,448:448,441:441,440:440,439:439,438:438,437:437,436:436,435:435,421:421,414:414,395:395,392:392,391:391,390:390,389:389,388:388,387:387,386:386,385:385,384:384,383:383,382:382,381:381,380:380,379:379,378:378,369:369").Select




Selection.Copy

    Sheets.Add after:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.Name = "test1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are shorter ways to represent your range, but whether they are real solutions to your problem depends on the max number of areas you may ever need to select.

E.g

```
Range("A401,A403,A405").EntireRow
```

uses a shorter range string than

```
Range("401:401,403:403,405:405")
```

but if you need to select many more rows then eventually that also will fail. As a workaround you could Union together two separate ranges:

```
... = Application.Union(Range(...), Range(...))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the range in a string as you did and then loop through each row and add it to the selected range.

```
Sub RangeSelectionTest()

    Dim selectedRange As range
    Dim row
    Dim rows As String
    Dim rowArray() As String

    'Define row selection string
    rows = "488:488,456:456,455:455,454:454,453:453,448:448,441:441,440:440,439:439,438:438,437:437,436:436,435:435,421:421,414:414,395:395,392:392,391:391,390:390,389:389,388:388,387:387,386:386,385:385,384:384,383:383,382:382,381:381,380:380,379:379,378:378,369:369,127:127,150:150"

    'Split to an array to loop
    rowArray = Split(rows, ",")

    ' Loop through all rows and add to range
    For Each row In rowArray
        If selectedRange Is Nothing Then
            Set selectedRange = range(row)
        Else
            Set selectedRange = Union(selectedRange, range(row))
        End If
    Next

    ' Select the range
    selectedRange.Select

End Sub
```

In fact, you can create a function that takes in a range string and returns the range object.

```
Sub SelectMyRange()
    Dim rows As String
    'Define row selection string
    rows = "488:488,456:456,455:455,454:454,453:453,448:448,441:441,440:440,439:439,438:438,437:437,436:436,435:435,421:421,414:414,395:395,392:392,391:391,390:390,389:389,388:388,387:387,386:386,385:385,384:384,383:383,382:382,381:381,380:380,379:379,378:378,369:369,127:127,150:150"

    Dim myRange As range
    Set myRange = RangeSelection(rows)
    myRange.Select
End Sub

Function RangeSelection(rangeString As String) As range

    Dim selectedRange As range
    Dim row
    Dim rowArray() As String

    'Split to an array to loop
    rowArray = Split(rangeString, ",")

    ' Loop through all rows and add to range
    For Each row In rowArray
        If selectedRange Is Nothing Then
            Set selectedRange = range(row)
        Else
            Set selectedRange = Union(selectedRange, range(row))
        End If
    Next

    ' Return the range
    Set RangeSelection = selectedRange

End Function
```